# Android Studio 2.1 update failed

Tags: android

When I upgraded the Android Studio to version 2.1, this error appeared...

```
--------ERROR:Update Failed---------

There was an error applying the update. If the problem persists, please download a full installation from the Android Studio download page.

Please report to https://https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.io.IOException: Cannot create temporary file: /tmp/jetbrains.patch.jar.androidstudio_copy
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.copyFile(Main.java:275)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.installPatch(Main.java:229)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:83)
```

Comment: does he have the full right and is there any space available on your hard drive ?

Comment: I don't know how to give it full right,and my hard drive has enough space.My system is Ubuntu ...

Comment: If the problem persists, please download a full installation from the Android Studio download page.

Comment: thank you all,I have solved this problem.

Comment: By this method： sudo sh studio.sh   ....I am so noob